# gpinitsystem unknown host mdw

Tags: linux, greenplum

I am sure that there are no extra spaces before or after your hostname(S) in the host file, and using `ssh mdw` can connect to `mdw`.
The `/etc/hosts` is like this:

```
 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
    ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

The error log:

```
20161209:21:01:14:030310 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Checking configuration parameters, please wait...
20161209:21:01:14:030310 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Reading Greenplum configuration file /home/gpadmin/gpconfigs/gpinitsystem_config
20161209:21:01:14:030310 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Locale has not been set in /home/gpadmin/gpconfigs/gpinitsystem_config, will set to default value
20161209:21:01:14:030310 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Locale set to en_US.utf8
20161209:21:01:15:030310 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-MASTER_MAX_CONNECT not set, will set to default value 250
20161209:21:01:15:030310 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Checking configuration parameters, Completed
20161209:21:01:15:030310 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Commencing multi-home checks, please wait...
.20161209:21:01:17:gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[FATAL]:-Unknown host mdw Script Exiting!
```

please.

Comment: /etc/hosts file you provided is from mdw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many hosts there are in your greenplum. Your `/etc/hosts` doesn't contain any information about `mdw` and `sdw`.

Assume you have two hosts named `mdw` and `sdw1` in your greenplum, both of the `/etc/hosts` files should be like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

172.31.25.24 mdw
172.31.16.170 sdw1
```

Replace the ip and host name with your own. Before try `gpinitsystem` again, you'd make sure you have performed `gpssh-exkeys` succesfully.

**UPDATE**:

I helped him with this issue using Skype. The answer is that his `gpadmin` account had no privilege to call `ping` utility, cause `gpinitsystem` calls `ping` to ensure any host in the DBMS exists.

Comment: My /etc/hosts files like this:

127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
172.18.210.7 mdw
172.18.210.8 smdw
172.18.210.9 sdw1
172.18.210.10 sdw2
and the hostnames of the four hosts are mdw,smdw,sdw1,sdw2.And I make sure I have performed gpssh-exkeys succesfully,because I can use those command "ssh mdw", "ssh smdw", "ssh sdw1", "ssh sdw2" to connect those hosts without password.But it still have this error.

Comment: Does your `gpssh`  work? Perform `$ gpssh -h mdw -h smdw -h sdw1 -hsdw2` on all your hosts to check if it works.

Comment: The command above missed a blank, should be `$ gpssh -h mdw -h smdw -h sdw1 -h sdw2`. And also, can you attach your error log?

Comment: The follow is my error log:{
20161208:15:49:46:013093 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Commencing multi-home checks, please wait...
.20161208:15:49:46:gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[FATAL]:-Unknown host mdw Script Exiting!}
And execute the command {$ gpssh -h mdw -h smdw -h sdw1 -h sdw2} will uotput follow log:{[gpadmin@mdw gpconfigs]$ gpssh -h mdw -h smdw -h sdw1 -h sdw2
Note: command history unsupported on this machine ...
=> }

Comment: That **Note** doesn't mean your `gpssh` fails. you can perform a command such as `ls` to check if it works.

Comment: Use the `ls` command has follow output:`[ mdw] gpAdminLogs  gpconfigs package
[sdw2]
[sdw1]
[smdw]`

Comment: I find that you are Chinese, so am I. you could leave me a mail address so that I can help you in Chinese someway. If an answer is found,  it will be posted here.

Comment: Thank you.I also find that you in Chengdu, so am I.My email address is `592174947@qq.com`. Looking forward to your message.Thanks again.